# Can I restore the content of a table after that I deleted all the rows inside it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, rdbms

I am very new in Microsoft **SQL Server** and I am not so into databasess.

Yesterday I made an error and I deletd all the rows inside the wrong table (I should delete the records in another table)

So now it is very important to me restore in some way all the deleted records in this table (only these records and not all the DB, if it is possibile in someway).

for completeness the table is named **dbo.VulnerabilityWorkaround** and have the following fields:

- **Id**: int not null (is the PK)
- **Description**: varchar(max), not null

I think that the SQL Server 
retains the information related to the deleted records in a log file (or in something like it, maybe a DB table...I don't know)

Can in some way restore my original **dbo.VulnerabilityWorkaround** by a query or something like it?

Comment: Unless you have a backup of the database (or table) your data is gone.

Comment: dbo.VulnerabilityWorkaround - oh the irony - ctrl Z, CTRL ZED!!!

Comment: @jenson-button-event do you mean that if I select my tbale and clicl CTRL Z it nullify my last delete operation?

Comment: I guess @jenson-button-event was making some kind of a cultural reference to something or someone called Zed. There is no `ctrl-z` method of undoing a DELETE (or any other change) in SQL Server. (Nor is there any reason to expect it to appear in the nearest future.)

Answer (score 0):

There is the transaction log, but as far as I know that can be used depending on the backup strategy the database instance has, meaning you would have to fire up a restore backup operation.

Other than restoring a previous backup, I don't think you have much options.

Since you just need one table it could be easier to restore a backup to a different server and then copy/move only the data you need using SSIS or Bulk Import/Export.